# Check CQL version with Cassandra and cqlsh?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

How do you check which cql version is currently being used in cqlsh?

In sql, you do this:

```
Select @@version
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to go about this.

From within cqlsh, you can simply `show version`.

```
aploetz@cqlsh> show version
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.8 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
```

However, that only works from within cqlsh.  Fortunately, you can also query `system.local` for that information as well.

```
aploetz@cqlsh> SELECT cql_version FROM system.local;

 cql_version
-------------
       3.2.0

(1 rows)
```

The `system.local` table has other useful bits of information about your current node, cluster, and Cassandra tool versions as well.  For more info, check it out with either `SELECT * FROM system.local;` (only has 1 row) or `desc table system.local`.

Comment: It works only if cassandra is started or running. There is an error in my case and cassandra is not running. In this case I can't find the cassandra version

Comment: @Ikrom The question was about the `cql_version`, not the Cassandra version.  If you want to find the Cassandra version of a node that is not running, you could always do a head -n 1 on CHANGES.txt: `head -n 1 CHANGES.txt`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I couldn't find CHANGES.txt file and used this command to find cassandra version `/usr/sbin/cassandra -v`