# "show version" in Cassandra and thrift protocol

Tags: java, cassandra, thrift

I would like to make sure that I can connect to the db from Java service from time to time (like ping). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31502671/411965) suggests to use `show version`.

My Java service is using the Cassandra thrift client (which is deprecated) and I couldn't find an example how to execute such a query.

I have a `client` of type `org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra.Client`.
Those are the methods I found that are similar:

```java
System.out.println("describe_schema_versions: " + nativeClient.describe_schema_versions());
System.out.println("describe_version: " + nativeClient.describe_version());
System.out.println("describe_snitch: " + nativeClient.describe_snitch());
System.out.println("describe_cluster_name: " + nativeClient.describe_cluster_name());
System.out.println("describe_keyspaces: " + nativeClient.describe_keyspaces());
System.out.println("describe_partitioner: " + nativeClient.describe_partitioner());
System.out.println("describe_token_map: " + nativeClient.describe_token_map());
```

How can I execute query to get Cassandra server version like this?

```
cqlsh> show version;
[cqlsh 3.1.8 | Cassandra 1.2.19 | CQL spec 3.0.5 | Thrift protocol 19.36.2]
```

Or is there an alternative query preferred as "ping"?

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246287/health-check-for-cassandra-connection-using-hector

Answer (score 2):

if you just want make a health check, i think run a simple query is a good choice.

```
 SELECT now() FROM system.local
```

here is the doc about how thrift client run query.
[Cassandra.Client (apache-cassandra API) - Javadoc Extreme](http://javadox.com/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-thrift/2.1.0/org/apache/cassandra/thrift/Cassandra.Client.html#execute_cql3_query%28java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Compression,%20org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ConsistencyLevel%29)

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting, but some folks have had a hard time with `system.now()` due to the integer format with Thrift.  This is largely due to the fact that system.local is a cql3 table, and not a Thrift column family.

To that end, this returns a string, which may be easier to deal with:

```
aploetz@cqlsh> SELECT release_version FROM system.local;

 release_version 
-----------------
          3.11.6 

(1 rows)
```

Or via the Cassandra CLI:

```
[default@system] get local['local']['release_version']
```

You can also pull `thrift_version`, if you'd rather do that (which is also a string).